# call dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event in gridview rowdatabound event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
protected void gvMeatDispatch_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dtpartyname = new DataTable();
        objRetailPL.status = 4;
        dtpartyname = objRetailBAL.GetType(objRetailPL);

        DropDownList ddlpn = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlpartyname");
        if (ddlpn != null)
        {
           // ddlpn.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(ddlbranchdate_SelectedIndexChanged);                

            ddlpn.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--", "0"));
            ddlpn.SelectedIndex = ddlpn.Items.Count - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

here ddlpn.SelectedIndexChanged event is not fired,...please help me
How to call dropdownlist selectedindexchanged event in Gridview RowDataBound event

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle `SelectedIndexChanged` for `DropDownList` nested inside `GridView` you have to just set `AutoPostback` property to true and point `SelectedIndexChange` event to some procedure.

The cause of issue I had was that I didn't check in Page_Load function (during binding data to GridView) following rule: `"If !IsPostBack "` . And that's all.

Comment: I follwed by above rules..but how to call that method?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have declared the following event in your code behind

```
void ddlpn_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```